# limiting versionControl.GetAllTeamProjects to specific folders

Tags: c#

I am not a .net person.  I use a tool whose c# code I took right off the internet to scan tfs for specific strings in files whose name patterns I can enter in a string list variable.  Examples of file name patterns are "*.dtsx","*.rdl" etc.  The critical lines of code are shown below.  A friend of mine who has been to more depts in the company than I and who probably has permissions on more tfs directories than I complained that the tool runs longer for her than the rest of us.  Presumably because more tfs directories are being searched.  Does someone know how I might limit these lines of code to search only the directory patterns entered in a list?

`var allProjs = versionControl.GetAllTeamProjects(true);`enter code here
`foreach (var teamProj in allProjs)
{`

Comment: Can you use the TeamProject Class Name property to limit which ones get searched?

Comment: i see a property called TeamProjectCollection but that seems to have something to do with ownership not directories.  I found a method called GetTeamProjectsForServerPaths and tried to use it as shown below.  But I'm still picking up info from other directories. `static string[] SearchDirectories = new[] {"$/ww/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyy/SSIS/"}; var allProjs = versionControl.GetTeamProjectsForServerPaths(SearchDirectories);`

Comment: i found the teamproject class name property but it doesn't look relevant.  In the mean time i may have found the answer.  The file patterns we were using always looked something like "*.dtsx" , "*.rdl" etc.  Little did I know (maybe) that the * can represent any number of path levels or nodes.  So i qualified the * with something like this and it may be working "xxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyy/SSIS/*.dtsx".

Comment: The file patterns are passed to the method below where versionControl is some sort of GetService object in TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory and teamProj is some sort of collection in TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory. `var items = versionControl.GetItems(teamProj.ServerItem + "/" + filePattern, RecursionType.Full).Items`

Answer (score 0):

yes, it looks like qualifying the file pattern list with directory nodes did the trick.  My friend's search time went from 20 minutes to about 20 seconds looking for one string.